# The thread number got via Thread.list.size is not the same with one via /proc

Tags: ruby, linux, multithreading, proc

Just look at the code first:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# encoding: UTF-8

thread_num = Thread.list.size
thread_num_via_proc = thread_num_later = nil
IO.readlines("/proc/#{Process.pid}/status").each do |line|
  if line.start_with?("Threads:")
    thread_num_via_proc = line.split[1].to_i
    thread_num_later = Thread.list.size
  end
end

p thread_num # 1
p thread_num_via_proc # 2
p thread_num_later # 1
```

The thread number, got from **/proc/[pid]/status**, is always equal to `Thread.list.size + 1`.

Then I referred to `man proc`, and it says(which confused me):

> - Threads: Number of threads in process containing this thread.

There should be something I have misunderstood, about "Thread.list" or "/proc/[pid]/status", will anyone points it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your program is perfectly correct, although it obviously will only work on systems that expose process information through /proc in that particular format.

Ruby's `Thread#list` is giving you *ruby's view of runnable threads* that are available to your program - you have 1 default `main` thread, and you can create others with `Thread#new`

`/proc/pid/status` is giving you the *operating system's count* of (native) threads. If you inspect any ruby program, at least on linux you will see that it always spawns two threads.

*e.g.* if you query a running ruby process with `ps -Lf` , you'll see the entries for each thread with a different value for **LWP** , and the thread count visible in **NLWP**

here's my output for an irb session

```
$ ps -Lfp 18991
UID        PID  PPID   LWP  C NLWP STIME TTY          TIME CMD
vagrant  18991 18906 18991  0    2 09:03 pts/9    00:00:00 irb                                              
vagrant  18991 18906 18992  0    2 09:03 pts/9    00:00:00 irb
```

I assume the other thread is for background ruby VM work, possibly the concurrent allocator/garage collector.